# Override and restore the normal functionality of Apple keyboard media keys in VLC?

Tags: itunes, keyboard, vlc

We're all used to the media keys in the top row of an Apple keyboard to command iTunes, even when some other application is frontmost.

If I have VLC frontmost, those media keys don't control iTunes but work as "next / previous" in VLC, which is a rather annoying exception because not does it only make iTunes controlling unreachable, it's plain unnecessary because to navigate within the frontmost application, the norm is to use arrow keys, or cmd+arrow.
How do I reserve the good old media keys for iTunes, always?

I'm on Yosemite.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Karabiner-Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements) to set the play/pause button (on my keyboard <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>) to *always* control iTunes from any App (I know Apps besides just VLC also commandeer the iTunes buttons sometimes).

Just add something like the following rule to `~/.config/karabiner/karabiner.json`

```
{  
   "description": "Play/pause button should only control iTunes.",
   "manipulators": [  
      {  
         "from": {  
            "key_code": "f7",
            "modifiers": {  
               "mandatory": [  
                  "fn"
               ]
            }
         },
         "to": [  
            {  
               "shell_command": "osascript -e 'tell application "iTunes" to previous track'"
            }
         ],
         "type": "basic"
      },
      {  
         "from": {  
            "key_code": "f8",
            "modifiers": {  
               "mandatory": [  
                  "fn"
               ]
            }
         },
         "to": [  
            {  
               "shell_command": "osascript -e 'tell application "iTunes" to playpause'"
            }
         ],
         "type": "basic"
      },
      {  
         "from": {  
            "key_code": "f9",
            "modifiers": {  
               "mandatory": [  
                  "fn"
               ]
            }
         },
         "to": [  
            {  
               "shell_command": "osascript -e 'tell application "iTunes" to next track'"
            }
         ],
         "type": "basic"
      }
   ]
}
```

Get rid of the `"modifiers"` part if you normally press <kbd>F8</kbd> *without* pressing <kbd>fn</kbd> to play/pause iTunes.

Then in Karabiner-Elements you'd add your new rule as a complex modification:

[image]

Comment: The newest version appears to only be for Sierra and later. I'm on Yosemite 10.10.5. There appears to be a list of older versions there but I'm having trouble finding any info on operating system compatibility of the old versions.

Comment: Yes, on [Karabiner's Download page](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) you can click the arrow next to the downloads button. There is an option for `Karabiner-10.22.0` which works with Yosemite

Comment: @user158589 any luck?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a third party tool. VLC has an open source heritage and they are all about customizing your apps to suit your personal preferences.

Open VLC and go to VLC > Preferences > Hotkeys

You can change what VLC uses there.

Note that you will likely have to change what is already set by VLC to change to your preference.

On my Mac it would not let me select just <kbd>F8</kbd> to change the keyboard shortcut for play/pause. I had to press <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd> to use the <kbd>F8</kbd> key as Play/Pause.

Comment: VLC settings were the first thing I went to look at, but by looking at the listing, I didn't find any visible reason to why the Apple media keys would command VLC. According to the hotkeys, space bar is play/pause, and cmd+arrow is next/previous. See these two screenshots: https://image.ibb.co/ezFkZn/Screen_Shot_2018_03_29_at_13_07_09.jpg       https://image.ibb.co/dMRES7/Screen_Shot_2018_03_29_at_13_07_45.jpg

Comment: What I was saying here is that you can *change* those key bindings without resorting to 3rd party apps. Functionality for what you want to do is built-in to VLC, but you have to change the key bindings already there.